# How to find and modify specific rows using fields in that row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset

```
time_in     time_out     total_mins
8AM         10AM         120
6AM         8AM          120
6AM         8AM          -231
```

What I am trying to do is get the wrong total_mins values, in this case the one that became negative. I wish to

1. identify the records with negative total_mins (Im ok with this)
2. recompute the timein and timeout difference and overwrite the existing total_mins value

I'm finding a lot of examples on how to use ix to get certain records based on a condition but what I am not sure about is how to use fields from that row, and use them to modify a certain field on a row. so basically, no. 2

only option that I can think of right now is to loop through the records, and perform test and modification but the documentation advises not to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need difference by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), get [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide by `60` for minutes.

Then change values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `mask`:

```
mask = df['total_mins'] < 0

s = (pd.to_datetime(df.loc[mask, 'time_out'], format='%H%p') - 
     pd.to_datetime(df.loc[mask, 'time_in'], format='%H%p'))
       .dt.total_seconds()
       .div(60)
       .astype(int)

print (s)
2    120
dtype: int32

df.loc[mask, 'total_mins'] = s
print (df)
  time_in time_out  total_mins
0     8AM     10AM         120
1     6AM      8AM         120
2     6AM      8AM         120
```

Alternative solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['total_mins'] = df['total_mins'].mask(mask, s)
print (df)
  time_in time_out  total_mins
0     8AM     10AM         120
1     6AM      8AM         120
2     6AM      8AM         120
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute the difference of all rows first:

```
total_mins_computed = (pd.to_datetime(df.time_out, format='%H%p') - pd.to_datetime(df.time_in', format='%H%p')).dt.total_seconds()
```

If you only want to correct the negative entries, use `np.where()`:

```
df['total_mins'] = np.where(df.total_mins > 0, df.total_mins, total_mins_computed)
```